# MySQL get SUMs of groups and avarage in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, self-join

I have a table:

```
+--------+------------+---------+
 id      | day        | status  |
+--------+------------+---------+
 1       | 2018-01-01 |  FAIL   |
 2       | 2018-01-02 | SUCCESS |
 3       | 2018-01-02 | SUCCESS |
 4       | 2018-01-02 | SUCCESS |
 5       | 2018-01-03 | SUCCESS |
 6       | 2018-01-03 |  FAIL   |
 7       | 2018-01-03 |  FAIL   |
 8       | 2018-01-04 | SUCCESS |
 9       | 2018-01-04 | SUCCESS |
 10      | 2018-01-05 | SUCCESS |
 11      | 2018-01-05 | SUCCESS |
 12      | 2018-01-05 | SUCCESS |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

I have to create a query that contains next information:

1. FAILs count of every day
2. SUCCESS count of every day
3. SUCCESS + FAILs count of every day
4. Percent of SUCCESS status of every day
5. For every day get an avarage value of SUCCESS percentage for three previous days starting from fourth record

I created a query to get info from 1-4 points:

```
SELECT day, fails, success, fails + success AS total, 
(success*100/(success+fails)) AS success_percent
FROM (
 SELECT day, 
 SUM(IF(status='FAIL',1,0)) AS fails, 
 SUM(IF(status='SUCCESS',1,0)) AS success 
 FROM statuses
 GROUP BY day)  AS inner_query;
```

But I don't know how to get a previous average values column for every record

Comment: You can probably more easily do that calculation in the application layer, unless you are using MySQL 8.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - unfortunately it's not possible to calculate it on application layer by design.

Comment: @ПавелВоевода ... please clarify as Python pandas, R, SAS, Excel, still others are powerful data analysis tools that can connect to MySQL to run any type of rowwise, conditional, rolling window aggregation. SQL is a special-purpose language meant for blockwise, set-based data retrieval. General-purpose languages can do practically any data wrangling needs.